# AngularJS > Logo links to /about when URL /home and then /home when URL /about

Tags: angularjs

I'm sure the answer is somewhere, but how do i link the same component (Navbar logo) to different pages depending on the URL.  I would like to link /about when Url= /home and then /home when Url= /about.

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })      
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'app/about/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .state('work', {
        url: '/work',
        templateUrl: 'app/work/work.html',
        controller: 'WorkCtrl'
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  });
```

**home.html**

```
<div class="page">
  <div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**navbar.html**

```
<nav class="navbar" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <a href="#/about"><h1>title</h1></a>

</nav>
```

**about.html**

```
<div class="page">
   <div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>
</div>
```

**NavbarCtrl**
* not sure what to do here, add a directive use ui.router use $location ??*

Hope someone can help, I've been thinking about it all week.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but wouldn't ng-show fit your needs? [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

You could check in it what is the location at the moment and show proper url depending on it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Iuser, however the ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute.   In my case I have states/urls that will redirect to that given URL. 

**In a nutshell:**  
Use the same navbar.html (see above) and change the route depending on wether the url is /home or /about. So when i click the <a link logo image> on the home it directs to the about page and then on the /about page the same element directs to the /home page. Like a vice versa / switch.

Comment: Correct, what I was thinking about is kind of workaround- you would just put two hrefs like: 
<a href="#/about" ng-show=""><h1>title</h1></a>
<a href="#/home" ng-hide=""><h1>title2</h1></a>

Comment: **Thanks!  this worked out with the following code:**
  .controller('NavbarCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.currentPath = $location.path();
  });
<a href="#/" ng-hide="currentPath === '/'"><h1>XXXX</h1></a>
   <a href="#/about" ng-hide="currentPath === '/about'"><h1>XXXX</h1></a>

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question I think. I would use [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute#!) and `$location` and I would probably create a directive for it.

Comment: I'm new to Angular JS, so let me recap that in layman's terms:
in NavCtrl add ngRoute and $location as the .config then in the same NavCtrl file make a directive. IF there was a solid example that shows me the way, it would be great. If not I will march on like a wounded soldier.

Comment: See [$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example)'s Plnkr example

Comment: I appreciate your help, is there nothing like a switch statement for my nav link:  
when /home=>/about : /about=>/home 
In the example link, the <a href="is_fixed">  so that confuses me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking me.